# Making a pause before redirecting to url after a link was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to make a post request once a link is clicked and after that to redirect to the url. A pause would be required to make sure that the post has enough time to be executed.

```
<a href="https://google.com/" class="click" target="_blank">Click me</a>

<script>
    $('.click').click(function() {
      // let's do this
      $.post( "https://postsomewhere.de/page=2&sort=price&direction=desc" );
      // and now it's time to open <a href> link       
    });
</script>
```

jQuery method preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make a pause. The second argument to `$.post` is the callback function which will be executed when the POST request completes. You can perform your redirect in here, like this:

```js
$('.click').on('click', e => {
  $.post("https://postsomewhere.de/page=2&sort=price&direction=desc", () => {
    window.location.assign(e.target.href);
  });
});
```